# JSON array of unkeyed containers (to parse in swift)

Tags: json, swift, sorting, date, parsing

How do I parse this? The array is unnamed, the objects are unnamed? I also need to sort it and find overlaps between events IF you guys have any advice there too it will be a huge help for me.

```
[{"title": "Evening Picnic", "start": "November 10, 2018 6:00 PM", "end": "November 10, 2018 7:00 PM"},
{"title": "Nap Break", "start": "November 8, 2018 12:56 PM", "end": "November 8, 2018 1:30 PM"}, 
{"title": "Football Game", "start": "November 3, 2018 6:14 PM", "end": "November 3, 2018 9:44 PM"}]
```

I'm new to swift and I'm wondering how to deal with this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON doesn't required you to implement an unkeyed container to parse it [unkeyed container sample](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52141492/2303865). What you need is a custom `DateFormatter` and `DateDecodingStrategy`. To sort your events you would need to conform it to `Comparable` protocol

This `DateFormatter` assumes your date string is a fixed date format with a local time:

```
extension Formatter {
    static let custom: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)
        formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        formatter.dateFormat = "MMMM d, yyyy h:mm a"
        return formatter
    }()
}
```

---

The custom `DateDecodingStrategy`:

```
extension JSONDecoder.DateDecodingStrategy {
    static let monthDayYearTime = custom {
        let container = try $0.singleValueContainer()
        let string = try container.decode(String.self)
        guard let date = Formatter.custom.date(from: string) else {
            throw DecodingError.dataCorruptedError(in: container,
                  debugDescription: "Invalid date: " + string)
        }
        return date
    }
}
```

---

Your `Codable` Event structure:

```
struct Event: Codable {
    let title: String
    let start: Date
    let end: Date
}
```

---

Conforming it to `Comparable` protocol

```
extension Event: Comparable {
    static func < (lhs: Event, rhs: Event) -> Bool { lhs.start < rhs.start }
}
```

---

A custom `description`:

```
extension Event: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String {
        "Title: \(title) - Start: \(Formatter.custom.string(from: start)) - End: \(Formatter.custom.string(from: end))"
    }
}
```

---

Playground testing:

Your JSON string:

```
let json = """
[{"title": "Evening Picnic", "start": "November 10, 2018 6:00 PM", "end": "November 10, 2018 7:00 PM"},
 {"title": "Nap Break", "start": "November 8, 2018 12:56 PM", "end": "November 8, 2018 1:30 PM"},
 {"title": "Football Game", "start": "November 3, 2018 6:14 PM", "end": "November 3, 2018 9:44 PM"}]
"""
```

---

Decoding your JSON

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .monthDayYearTime
do {
    let events = try decoder.decode([Event].self, from: Data(json.utf8))
    print(events.sorted())
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

This will print

> [Title: Football Game - Start: November 3, 2018 6:14 PM - End:
>   November 3, 2018 9:44 PM, Title: Nap Break - Start: November 8, 2018
>   12:56 PM - End: November 8, 2018 1:30 PM, Title: Evening Picnic -
>   Start: November 10, 2018 6:00 PM - End: November 10, 2018 7:00 PM]

Comment: I love you. 1 more thing, can you help me with finding out overlapping dates in this format??

Comment: the link to the new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60142054/parse-json-array-in-swift-sort-it-and-find-overlapping-dates