# parse JSON array in swift , sort it and find overlapping dates

Tags: ios, swift, sorting, date, overlapping

How do I parse this? The array is unnamed, the objects are unnamed? I also need to sort it and find overlaps(identify conflicts) between events IF you guys have any advice there too it will be a huge help for me.

```
[{"title": "Evening Picnic", "start": "November 10, 2018 6:00 PM", "end": "November 10, 2018 7:00 PM"}, {"title": "Nap Break", "start": "November 8, 2018 12:56 PM", "end": "November 8, 2018 1:30 PM"}, {"title": "Football Game", "start": "November 3, 2018 6:14 PM", "end": "November 3, 2018 9:44 PM"}, {"title": "Evening Cookout with Friends", "start": "November 6, 2018 5:00 PM", "end": "November 6, 2018 10:00 PM"}, {"title": "Roller Derby", "start": "November 7, 2018 12:00 PM", "end": "November 7, 2018 2:30 PM"}, {"title": "Basketball Game", "start": "November 8, 2018 7:30 PM", "end": "November 8, 2018 10:30 PM"}, {"title": "Local Pub with Friends", "start": "November 1, 2018 7:33 PM", "end": "November 1, 2018 11:00 PM"}, {"title": "Dentist Appointment", "start": "November 10, 2018 1:45 PM", "end": "November 10, 2018 2:30 PM"}, {"title": "Volleyball With Friends", "start": "November 6, 2018 12:00 PM", "end": "November 6, 2018 1:26 PM"}, {"title": "Free Donuts", "start": "November 9, 2018 3:00 PM", "end": "November 9, 2018 4:00 PM"}, {"title": "TV Show Marathon", "start": "November 9, 2018 4:30 PM", "end": "November 9, 2018 9:00 PM"}, {"title": "Boba Tea Grand Opening", "start": "November 6, 2018 1:27 PM", "end": "November 6, 2018 2:00 PM"}, {"title": "Lunch with Friends", "start": "November 8, 2018 11:30 AM", "end": "November 8, 2018 12:59 PM"}, {"title": "SF Coffee Festival","start": "November 6, 2018 6:00 PM","end": "November 6, 2018 9:00 PM"}, {"title": "Beer with Friends", "start": "November 9, 2018 8:00 PM", "end": "November 9, 2018 9:30 PM"}, {"title": "Yoga", "start": "November 1, 2018 6:00 PM", "end": "November 1, 2018 7:33 PM"}, {"title": "Rock Concert", "start": "November 7, 2018 6:30 PM", "end": "November 7, 2018 11:00 PM"}, {"title": "Lunch Meeting", "start": "November 9, 2018 12:30 PM", "end": "November 9, 2018 2:30 PM"}, {"title": "Bicycling with Friends", "start": "November 1, 2018 6:00 AM", "end": "November 1, 2018 9:30 AM"}, {"title": "Birthday Party", "start": "November 10, 2018 12:30 PM", "end": "November 10, 2018 8:30 PM"}, {"title": "Football Tailgate with John", "start": "November 3, 2018 6:14 PM", "end": "November 3, 2018 9:44 PM"}]
```

I'm new to swift and I'm wondering how to deal with this

Comment: The first thing I would do is create a `Codable` struct so that you can get your JSON into an array of such structs.  You might want to write custom decoding code to parse the date strings into `Date`s (Note that having strings like that in JSON isn't great - What time zone are these dates in?).  Once you have the array of structs you can sort it by start date and then iterate over it looking for overlaps; If the subsequent event starts before the current event ends then you have an overlap.  The reason for parsing the strings into `Date`s is that it makes comparisons trivial

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering this is a follow up question from your previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60132662/2303865). You can use Swift [DateInterval](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateinterval) initialiser to create a `DateInverval` with your `start` and `end` dates and check if they intersects with each other:

```
extension Event {
    var interval: DateInterval { .init(start: start, end: end) }
    func intersects(with event: Event) -> Bool { interval.intersects(event.interval) }
}
```

---

To check for conflicting events you would need to make your Event conform to Equatable and filter the ones that intersects with them but are not the same event:

```
struct Event: Codable, Equatable {
    let title: String
    let start: Date
    let end: Date
}
```

---

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .monthDayYearTime
do {
    let events = try decoder.decode([Event].self, from: Data(json.utf8))
    print(events.sorted())
    let conflictingEvents: [(Event, Event)] = events.compactMap {
        for event in events where event != $0 {
            if event.intersects(with: $0) && $0.end != event.start && event.end != $0.start { return ($0, event) }
        }
        return nil
    }
    print(events.count)             // "21\n"
    print(conflictingEvents.count)  // "11\n"
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: Is this most efficient? I was thinking I might need something like a loop through the array to find that. Which one is more efficient?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by efficiency, This is the way to go about working with date intervals. You need to decide which events you are going to check if overlap with each other. As I already said you should provide some dates that overlap with each other in your post and the expected result. Please take a look at how to provide a [mcve]

Comment: I updated the input to the full json array in the post

Comment: @AliAbraham So do you need to filter out the ones that intersect with each other or to keep only the ones that intersects?

Comment: @AliAbraham Note that SO it is not a code writing service you need to show a minimum effort trying to solve your issues

Comment: I need to identify conflicts between events

Comment: I'm making the attempts but I tried the for loops and I keep messing up I think my approach is very wrong I just need the correct approach and guidance. When you gave me soultion on the first post I realized my aproach was very wrong.

Comment: You would need to check each element of your events against the events without itself.

Comment: After sorting, I'm trying to check the end date of each element with the start date of the next element. but I'm still running into bugs. Is this the best approach in your opinion?

Comment: This solution is great but it gives the count of conflicts and doesn't identify them

Comment: The conflictingEvents is a collection with all of them

Comment: Excellent but 1 more thing: If an event ends the same time the next event starts it's NOT conflicting. I'll do some changes in the == , != to try and fix that

Comment: Thank you So Very Much. I don't know how I can properly express how thankful I am.

Comment: Is there a way I can upvote you or give you a recommendation or something like that

Comment: you would need to first gain some reputation and then you could add a bounty to the post

Comment: can you check this post   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60154926/swift-change-cell-background-colors-in-some-tableview-cells

Answer (score 0):

There are only two "difficult" things with your JSON structure which might make it throw a spanner in the works.

The fact that's it a straight up JSON array and the non-standard date format.

I would recommend starting with a good tutorial, something like [Ultimate Guide to JSON Parsing with Swift](https://benscheirman.com/2017/06/swift-json/), which is may de-facto source, as it covers almost all the use-cases I've had to date.

Start by defining a construct to hold the basic data and conform to the `Codable` protocol

```
struct Event: Codable {
    let title: String
    let end: Date
    let start: Date
}
```

Create a `JSONDecoder` and provide it with a custom `dateDecodingStrategy`

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "MMMM dd, yyyy hh:mm a"

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(formatter)
```

You need to convert you JSON response to `Data`.  I might already be in this format or you can convert the `String` text directly, which I did for my testing

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "MMMM dd, yyyy hh:mm a"
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(formatter)
```

Finally, decode the response...

```
let events = try decoder.decode([Event].self, from: data)
```

From there you can start processing the data.

Sorting a array and date comparison is such a readily asked question, there are just simply so many examples to choose from, I'm not going to try and repeat it here.  Do some research, try some ideas.  If you're still having issues, as another (focused) question and provide your attempts

Comment: `hh:mm` a is wrong it should be `h:mm a`. The same applies to the day. You should also set your `DateFormatter`'s locale to `"en_US_POSIX"` to avoid it reflecting the user's device locale and settings like the 12h/24h time settings

Comment: @LeoDabus Since we're passing a `String` back to `Date`, I'm not sure that `hh:mm a` or `h:mm a` is going to make any difference, it would going the other way, but I'm hedging my bets (and I did test the code).  Yes to `en_US_POSIX`

Comment: yes `DateFormatter` is kind of lenient but I avoid giving it a chance to fail :)

Comment: @LeoDabus It's kind of way I edge on the side of caution - but, since it's just guide/example, here's hopping that the OP can modify it to there needs ;)

Comment: can you check this post         https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60154926/swift-change-cell-background-colors-in-some-tableview-cells